# how to use session with php and angularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, session

I am working with angularJS and PHP backend, and I need to select data of authenticated user and use it in angularJS to diplay this data. 
I have two php files, login.php and select.php where I have to select authenticated user data. and two controllers one for login and the second to recuperate selected data. I tried to use session and token but I get this error in php: undefinded index token in select.php file.

**login.php**

```
<?php  
session_start();
$_SESSION['token'] = true;
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "salma");    
if(count($data) > 0){ 

$Email=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->Email);
$mdp=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->mdp);   
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE (EmailClient = "'.$Email.'" AND   mdp= "'.$mdp.'")';

$q = mysqli_query($connect , $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 )
  { 
       $token = md5($Email.time()."51395+81519851");
       $query = "UPDATE client SET token = '".$token."' WHERE EmailClient = '".$Email."'";
       mysqli_query($connect , $query);
       $_SESSION["token"] = "$token; 
       $_SESSION["Email"] = $Email; 

       $result['email'] =$Email;
       $result['role'] = 'client';
       $result['token'] = $token;

       $resultstring=json_encode($result);
       $resultstring=str_replace("null", '""', $resultstring);
       echo $resultstring;
       exit;

  }
```

**select.php**

```
<?php  
session_start();
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "salma");  
 $query = "SELECT NomClient,PrenomClient,EmailClient FROM client WHERE token ='".$_SESSION["token"]."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output[] = $row;  
      }  
      echo json_encode($output);  
 }  

 ?>
```

Comment: what is display.php ? . also have you try to use jwt (json web token), and your bakend is pulerly php or using a framework like lumen, slimphp, or simething else. i recomend this article (https://www.sitepoint.com/php-authorization-jwt-json-web-tokens/)

Comment: I m sorry, it s select.php, and the backend is purely php, I already read the turorial that you suggest but I still don't know how to apply jwt, that's why I tried to use the session as first step. Thank you

Comment: well let me explain.  if you have separatly the front and the backend, you cant make session, cause each one are on diferent path. you need to use jwt or cookies for authentication. i recomend jwt as i say the article is pretty well explained, also you can make your php with slim or lumen who are a miniframeworks  you can use to make a rest api.

Comment: if you want use session, the front and back need to be the same. i mean php contains html embede and javascript, like oldschool days.

Comment: Aaah thank you, Thank you for warning me about this, I will try to apply jwt . thank you